# Can I really feed crawdads to cows in Stardew Valley?

Tags: stardew-valley

Jas *claims* to have fed a crawdad to a cow.

[image: Jas Dialogue: I look for crawdads in the river...]

According to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Crayfish), a crawdad is just another name for a crayfish. Since you can catch crayfish in the game, I thought that my bovine companions would be delighted to receive one as a treat. However, when I left or right-click the cow while holding a crayfish, the cow's status box pops up and I can't seem to find a way to hand over the crustacean.

[image: Trying to feed my cow a crayfish]

Is Jas just a big fat liar? Can I actually feed crayfish (and potentially other strange things) to my cow? If so, what effect does it have?

Comment: Similarly, Marnie gave me a quest to gather Amaranth because cows love it apparently. I don't know if you can actually do it though.

Comment: I had a similar experience when Willie asked for a tuna and I tried to give him an albacore... Apparently Stardew residents follow different species-naming conventions.

Comment: Sorry Brysonic, didn't mean to [throw your title under the bus](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/revisions/358739/4)!

Answer (score 62, accepted):

You can't feed crayfish to cows, the only way to interact with them is to pet them or milk them; Jas' story is just more plot.

As an aside, I don't think feeding crayfish to cows is very healthy for either of them.

Comment: We [in fact do](http://www.motherjones.com/blue-marble/2013/12/cow-feed-chicken-poop-candy-sawdust) feed crayfish to cows.

Comment: I don't think being fed to something else is beneficial in any sense at all.

Comment: @MarchHo What do you know! It was forbidden for a while in the EU because of BSE.